# Which publishers use TeX and friends for a significant proportion of their published books?

Tags: big-list, tex-general

Which publishers use TeX and derivatives (LaTeX, ConTeXt, and friends) for a significant proportion of their published *books*? Note that I am not asking about journals.

I'll leave the interpretation of "significant proportion" open. "Most books within a few subfields" counts; but if it's only "most math, physics, and computer science books" (which will be true in a lot of cases), please indicate so in your answer, as this will help us see which publishers try to use systems from the TeX family *even in fields where (La)TeX doesn't dominate*.

**Note: All publishers regardless of size or fame are welcome in answers.** If we need to regroup the answers into categories (such as "university presses", "large international corporation$", "publishers focusing on locale X or language Y"), we can still do that later.

Comment: Note: It's subjective; feel free to improve the question.

Comment: I am guessing that the answer will first and foremost include some university presses and small independent publishers run by technically-minded people, but let's see what we can find out!

Answer (score 30):

There was a thread on this on TeXHax a while back: http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2007-June/008538.html

And that discussion resulted in this web page: http://www.ccrnp.ncifcrf.gov/~toms/latex.html#tex-latex_publishers

I trimmed a few out-dated entries, and did not consider the ``significant'' aspect:

- aaai www.aaai.org
- AAAS/science www.sciencemag.org
- American Chemical Society Publications
- Addison-Wesley
- algebra universalis
- American Institute of Physics www.aip.org
- American Mathematical Society
- American Meteorological Society www.ametsoc.org
- American Physical Society authors.aps.org
- Beech Stave Press
- Birkhäuser
- Cambridge University Press
- CRC
- Documenta Mathematica www.math.uiuc.edu
- Docscape
- Elsevier
- Engine House Books
- Fondo de Cultura Económica
- Informs joc.pubs.informs.org
- Institut Mittag-Leffler (Royal Swedish Academy of Sciences)
- www.arkivformatematik.org
- IOP (institute of physics) authors.iop.org
- John Benjamins Publishing Company
- London Mathematical Society books www.lms.ac.uk
- Louisiana State University Press
- Mathematical Association of America www.maa.org
- National Research Council of Canada
- Oxford University Press www.oup.co.uk
- Princeton University Press press.princeton.edu
- Publications de l'Institut Mathématique (Beograd) www.emis.de
- SAS Institute
- SIAM books www.siam.org
- Springer math www.springer.com
- Springer physics www.springer.com
- Thomson Delmar Learning
- UIT Cambridge
- Unipress (Institute of High Pressure Physics, Polish Academy of Sciences)
- www.unipress.waw.pl
- University of California Press
- Wiley www.wiley.com
- William Andrew Publishing
- World Scientific
- WordTech

Answer (score 14):

Since you're not worried about size or fame, my publishing company [Dickimaw Books](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/) uses LaTeX for all my text books, illustrated children's fiction and crime fiction. (The ebook was somewhat more complicated as it needed TeX4HT and some post-processed tweaking, but the original source was LaTeX.)

Comment: Glad to hear, keep rocking...

Answer (score 8):

Hindawi http://www.hindawi.com/ (a publisher of open access academic journals, based on Egypt), use TeX exclusively for their printed editions.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this counts but I have created, with contributing writers, two books of computer-mediated experimental literature.  LaTeX was the only typesetting system that could cope with the weirdness:

- [exquisite_code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Exquisite_code-Edit-Software-Python/dp/1906496471/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388794037&sr=1-5&keywords=exquisite_code)
- [Heroic Real Estate Otter of the 21st Century](http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/excode)

Also, the Brussels based art collective [Constant](http://constantvzw.org/site/-Projects,1-.html) do quite a few catalogs and publications with LaTeX, as well as the professionals in their open-source design spin-off [OSP](http://ospublish.constantvzw.org/blog/).

Answer (score 7):

The [Verlag Antike](http://verlag-antike.de) (a german publishing house for Classics) uses LaTeX/XeLaTeX for some of its books.

Answer (score 6):

The Polish publisher `Biblioteka Słońca i Księżyca` http://www.bsik.pl/ uses LaTeX for non-scientific literature. (There are some problems with subpages  on mentioned homepage now.)

Answer (score 4):

I know a designer and editor (who in fact is the Director) who makes books about social sciences and humanities using LaTeX. The publishing company (sic) is [Ediciones Imago Mundi](http://edicionesimagomundi.com/sobre-nosotros/). I don't know if all their production is, but a significant part is made with LaTeX and BibLaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

[Morgan & Claypool](http://www.morganclaypool.com/) use LaTeX for typesetting.

Comment: How can you tell that they use Y&Y?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with them, but I thought I remembered seeing some comments to this effect in one of their style files. I can't find them at the moment; I've edited this out of my answer since I can't confirm.

Comment: @marczellm Just remembered how I knew: `LY1` font encodings. :)

Comment: @PaulGessler It doesn't follow that they use Y&Y fonts, though. *If* they use Computer Modern, I guess that would be Y&Y but it needn't be otherwise. (Latin Modern, for example, supports LY1.)

Answer (score 4):

[Language Science Press](http://langsci-press.org/), which publishes peer-reviewed open-access books in linguistics, uses LaTeX for all typesetting.

Answer (score 4):

[Edition Topoi](http://www.edition-topoi.org) from the German Excellence Cluster [Topoi](http://www.topoi.org) uses LaTeX.

Topoi is a cooperation of the Humboldt-Universität zu Berlin, Freie Universität Berlin, the Berlin-Brandenburg Academy of Sciences and Humanities, the German Archaeological Institute, the Max Planck Institute for the History of Science and the Stiftung Preußischer Kulturbesitz.

Answer (score 3):

Italian publisher [**Aracne editrice**](http://www.aracneeditrice.it/aracneweb/) uses LaTeX not only for scientific subject books, but also for humanistic books and essays. Their proprietary class uses Monotype's Dante typeface ([example](http://www.aracneeditrice.it/pdf/9788854859654.pdf)) for body text and Helvetica Condensed for tables.

Italian as well and even bigger than Aracne, **Zanichelli** uses LaTeX too ([source](http://www.dcuci.univr.it/documenti/AttDidAva/allegato/allegato877254.pdf)).

Answer (score 3):

The [**European Mathematical Society** Publishing House](https://www.ems-ph.org/home.php).

Answer (score 2):

The ACM currently uses TeX for their book series.

http://books.acm.org/