# Latex and non-scientific publications

Tags: book-design, publishing, software

I've been using LaTeX for a few years now and I feel more or less comfortable with typing up my mathematical documents with it.

However, I still wonder if LaTeX is also used for *non-scientific* publications, say in literature books that contain almost no formulas.

My question is not quite about whether TeX **can** handle those situations, but rather whether TeX **should** (or is still **recommended to**) be used in those contexts. On a different but related note, what softwares do big publishers (such as Oxford, Cambridge, etc) normally use for typesetting their books?

To clarify my questions, let me provide some context. Recently I learned that a linguist friend of mine has decided to publish her own book and is looking for a "modern" software for her beloved piece of work. I was hesitant to recommend LaTeX to her immediately, because I wasn't sure whether it would be the right choice for her. I would appreciate it if experienced users could share their thoughts on this.

Thanks much!

Comment: You can have a look at [Visual comparison between LaTeX, Word, Indesign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110133/visual-comparison-between-latex-and-word-output-hyphenation-typesetting-ligat) and [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) to start with.

Comment: In short: Do you know anything better that LaTeX? This will have only  opinion-based answers,   but in TeX.SX   it's like asking in a synagogue if there is a better religion than Judaism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What professions use TeX/LaTeX besides CS?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/940/what-professions-use-tex-latex-besides-cs)

Comment: Note that we have a [liguistics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) tag here, indicating that (i) linguists use LaTeX; (ii) packages for linguistics exist; (iii) there's somewhere to ask for help

Comment: Also, you can have a look at [Which publishers use TeX and friends for a significant proportion of their published books?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151613/which-publishers-use-tex-and-friends-for-a-significant-proportion-of-their-publi).

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX is an excellent tool for diagramming content for books whose content is mostly text and no just graphics (fos a desing book or a illustrated one), it is an excellent free software tool especially for those who come from the world of science and feel more comfortable with codes languaje, and also it may be simpler to use than indesign . On the web you can find downloadable templates, I spent a link so you can show examples. http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/books.